# Create an IEnumerable<SelectListItem> collection off a given type T in a generic class

Tags: c#, generics, selectlistitem

I'm wanting to add a method which will create a IEnumerable for entities in my project. All of the entities will have a drop down rendered for capturing / editing, so in my mind, it makes sense to add this to my generic repository method.

I'm not quite sure if this is feasible, or how best to approach this, as I'm using generic classes, hope the following piece of code sells my idea:

```
public interface ISpaceRepository<T> 
    where T : class
{
    SpaceResult<T> GetAll();
    SpaceResult<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    SpaceResult<T> Add(T entity);
    SpaceResult<T> Delete(T entity);
    SpaceResult<T> Edit(T entity);
    SpaceResult<T> FindById(int id);
    SpaceResult<T> SelectList();
}
```

Very basic interface definition. This gets implemented in my SpaceRespository class:

```
public class SpaceRepository<T>
    : ISpaceRepository<T> where T : class
{
    // content omitted for ease of reading
}
```

Within my repository, I'd like to create the a method that will build up the IEnumerable collection, for the type T. The problem here is that, by default, T exposes no properties, so I can't get T.Name and T.Id, so am playing around with a predicate to get the job done:

```
    public SpaceResult<T> SelectList(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        SpaceResult<T> result = new SpaceResult<T>();

        try
        {
            result.SelectList = this.GetAll().Select(predicate);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            result.IsError = true;
            result.Message = ex.Message;
            result.InnerException = ex.InnerException.Message;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

This approach works, but I have to define the predicate every time I'm building a collection of select items to bind to a Drop Down List in Razor (MVC).

Is there maybe an easier way? Reflection is too costly. There is no particular reason for not doing this at the view model level, I'm just playing around with a couple of ideas while learning :$.

**Update**

The idea is to expose a generic method that will create a collection of SelectListItem elements for a given database entity of T, within the repository pattern, without having me or another developer duplicating the code for each of the tables in the database.

**Update 1**

An example:

```
ISpaceRepository<Building> _repo = new SpaceRepository<Building>();


SpaceResult<Building> result = this._repo.SelectList((x => new SelectListItem { 
  x.Id, 
  x.Description }));
```

**Update 2**

Building looks like this:

```
[Table("buildings")]
public class Building
{
    [Column("id")]
    [Key]
    public int Id {get;set;}

    [Column("description")]
    public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

So was thinking that maybe if I add a custom attribute to the columns I need in the select list, I'd be able to use reflection, but this sounds expensive for the solution I'm after.

```
[Table("buildings")]
public class Building
{
    [Column("id")]
    [Key]
    [SelectListItem]
    public int Id {get;set;}

    [Column("description")]
    [SelectListItem]
    public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: "This gets inherited in my SpaceRespository class:" - nitpick: As `ISpaceRepository<T>` is an interface, it gets *implemented* in your `SpaceRepository` class.

Comment: Can you show an exemplary `predicate` function? Do the different types for `T` have no common ancestor that would provide any properties common to all possible types `T`?

Comment: not really, i didn't design this with a select list in mind, it came up afterwards. i'd do something like (x => new SelectListItem { x.Id, x.Description }), because not all tables have description as the text value, it's either description, or name, or title (bad database design, 3rd party)

Comment: Well, that's not a `predicate` function, but some other type-specific function that provides some information on the items - one that you may want to pass into `SelectList`, so you can use its return value in the method, though.

Comment: I'm still learning this stuff, come from UI development HTML / JavaScript mostly, so thank you for correcting me :). I am using the return though, just thought there might be an easier way of doing this :$

Comment: Are the entities in your project at your disposal, can you make them implement an interface?

Comment: I can, was just looking into something similar. Was thinking if I decorate the required columns, usually the primary key (id) and at least one text column, with a custom attribute, I'd be able to use reflection, but this sounds expensive? I've been warned against using reflection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about :

```
interface IEntity {
    public int Id { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
}

[Table("buildings")]
public class Building : IEntity
{
    [Column("id")]
    [Key]
    public int Id {get;set;}

    [Column("description")]
    public string Description {get;set;}

    [NotMapped]
    public string Name { get { return this.Description; } }
}

[Table("cars")]
public class Car : IEntity
{
    [Column("id")]
    [Key]
    public int Id {get;set;}

    [Column("title")]
    public string Title {get;set;}

    [NotMapped]
    public string Name { get { return this.Title; } }
}
```

and then instead of a generic method, is writing one that works on elements that implement this interface suffices?

The Method:

```
public SpaceResult<IEntity> SelectList() 
{
    SpaceResult<IEntity> result = new SpaceResult<IEntity>();

    try
    {
        result.SelectList = this.GetAll().Select(x => new SelectListItem { x.Id, x.Name });
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        result.IsError = true;
        result.Message = ex.Message;
        result.InnerException = ex.InnerException.Message;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Usage :

```
ISpaceRepository<Building> _repo = new SpaceRepository<Building>();
SpaceResult<IEntity> result = this._repo.SelectList();
```

or

```
ISpaceRepository<Car> _repo = new SpaceRepository<Car>();
SpaceResult<IEntity> result = this._repo.SelectList();
```

As long as all your entity classes implement the common interface, the same method can be applied.

Comment: that can work yes, but i want to create a generic method in my repository pattern that caters for all tables in my database, allowing them to expose an IEnumerable<SelectListItem> without the need to recreate this method for each one of the tables in the view model. If that makes sense?

Comment: It does make sense. But what I am suggesting is not much different. I will eloborate my answer shortly.

Comment: I'm playing with the idea you pointed out. Basically, T implements IEntity, and it only has two properties, so these are the properties that will be used to build up the items...

Comment: Correct. Moreover by this way, the responsiblity to define how a SelectListItem should be generated is partly eleborated to the entities.

Comment: this pretty much guided me in the right direction, thank you @tafa.